# whats the best way to transform a dataframe into a specific format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe like

```
df_given =    B   D   X
           1  B1  D1  X1
           2  B2  D2  X2
           3  B3  D3  X3
           4  B4  D4  X4
```

and i would like to turn it into

```
 df_want =    A   B   C   D
           1  0   B1  0   D1
           2  0   B2  0   D2
           3  0   B3  0   D3
           4  0   B4  0   D4
```

My real example has hundreds of columns so i cannot add or remove columns by hand. 
I've tried to start with an empty dataframe (the way i'd like to have it in the end) and append rows from the given dataframe. But

```
 df_want = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
 df_want.append(df_given)
```

gives

```
    A   B   C   D   X
 1  NaN B1  NaN D1  X1
 2  NaN B2  NaN D2  X2
 3  NaN B3  NaN D3  X3
 4  NaN B4  NaN D4  X4
```

The NaNs aren't the problem. The additional columns like X are.
Is that the right way to go anyway?

Comment: How are `A` and `C` chosen? How are columns like `X` chosen?

Comment: Not sure of the logic behind maybe explicit a bit more why you add or remove some columns, but at least in your example, using [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) should work like `df.reindex(columns=['A','B','C','D'], fill_value=0)`

Comment: Imagine the columns i would like to have being something like `list(map(chr, range(65, 80)))`. Some of them show up in the given data, and some don't. Columns like `X` represent those in the given data which i would like to get rid of by starting with an empty dataframe with only those columns that i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use what @BEN.T recommends:

Where,

```
print(df)

    B   D   X
1  B1  D1  X1
2  B2  D2  X2
3  B3  D3  X3
4  B4  D4  X4
```

Use reindex,

```
df.reindex([*'ABCD'], axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C   D
1  0  B1  0  D1
2  0  B2  0  D2
3  0  B3  0  D3
4  0  B4  0  D4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to re-arrange the columns, remove a column, add a column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# step 1: create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(B=['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
         D=['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4'],
         X=['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4']
        )
)

print('original dataframe:')
print(df)
print()

# step 2: save the columns in a list
cols = df.columns

print('print the column names:')
print(cols)
print()

# step 3: change the column order, exclude 'X'
new_col_order = ['D', 'B']

# step 4a: create new dataframe
df_new = df[new_col_order]

print('new dataframe: ')
print(df_new)
print()

# step 4b: alternative way, use 2 sets of square brackets to call the columns in a list
print('original dataframe, re-arrange columns: ')
print(df[['D', 'B']])
print()

# step 5: add a new column to dataframe
df_new['A'] = np.NaN

print('new dataframe with added column: ')
print(df_new)
print()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the aswer but maybe i should have been more specific in my question. With "i cannot add or remove columns by hand" i meant that "df_new['A'] = np.NaN" or the like aren't an option for me because there are hundreds of columns. I cant't go through each of them in this way. I just wanted to keep the example above simple.